# Add wiremock stub mapping with xml response via robot framework

Tags: xml, robotframework, wiremock

I'm using robot framework to post new stub mapping in wiremock. Stub mapping response has to have xml format. I have problem with JSON parsing due to used xml.

```
${xml_content}    Set Variable    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"></soap:Envelope>
${body}    Set Variable    {"request": { "url": "/test/2.0/TestB", "method": "POST", "bodyPatterns": [{"contains" : "test_id"}]}, "response": { "status": 200, "headers":{"Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=UTF-8"}, "body": "${xml_content}"}}
${resp}    Post Request    ${session}    /__admin/mappings/new    data=${body}    headers=${headers}
```

I'm getting following error:

```
{"errors" : [ {
"code" : 10,
"source" : {
  "pointer" : "/"
},
"title" : "Error parsing JSON",
"detail" : "Cannot construct instance of `com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.stubbing.StubMapping` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{\"request\": { \"url\": \"/test/2.0/TestB\", \"method\": \"POST\", \"bodyPatterns\": [{\"contains\" : \"test_id\"}]}, \"response\": { \"status\": 200, \"headers\":{\"Content-Type\": \"text/xml; charset=UTF-8\"}, \"body\": \"<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"></soap:Envelope>\"}}')"} ]}
```

I have tried to use string instead of xml as value of ${xml_content} variable. In that case stub mapping is created correctly. So the problem is with parsing xml.

Could you please advice me how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Are you aware that `${body}` is being set to a string, not a dictionary?

Comment: How this fact can help me to solve a problem? Could you please advise me how to avoid getting described error from wiremock?

Comment: I've never used wiremock so I don't know about that. However, your `${body}` is not valid json which is probably the root of the problem.

Comment: husband find solution: ${xml_content}    Set Variable    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\\\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\\\"></soap:Envelope> Using triple backslashes to escape double quots. Anyway thank for your comments.